# gapi.auth.signOut(); doesn't actually logout the user

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

This might be a really dumb question, but I need help.
 I have a website that authenticates a user through OAuth with their Google accounts. The problem is that after I press logOut button (now the token is null), if I press again the logIn button the pop-up used for credentials, this one: [image]

doesn't appear and the client is logged automatic.. ..
I don't have any more ideas about this problem..

Thank you

`gapi.auth.signOut();
if (!gapi.auth.getToken()) {
    console.info('Now signed out, token null.');
}`

this is my signout code, and the info appears into the console. I use angular-google-plus.js and my login looks like this:

```
 GooglePlus.login().then(function(authResult) {

            if (authResult['access_token'] && !authResult.error) {
                var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;

                gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', apiClientLoaded);

            } else {
                $scope.welcomeMsgGoogle = "autentificare eronata";
            }
        });


           function apiClientLoaded() {
        gapi.client.plus.people.get({ 'userId': 'me' }).execute(handleEmailResponse);
    }
    function handleEmailResponse(user) {
        var accessToken2 = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
        gapi.auth.setToken(accessToken2);
    /// some code

    }
```

I try to use `cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin'` and still doesn't work..

Comment: If I understood correctly, then this is normal.. oauth2 with google works the same way you install an app in android .. you accepts the scopes in the first time, and the app is granted access .. which means the user will not need to see this screen everytime

Comment: ... but I press the logOut button.. and the user is still logged

Comment: .. the user is never really logged out from your application. what you can do is create a logout screen.. next time the user comes he will be automatically logged in.. and don't do an aggressive Logout because then you will log the user out of google : )

Comment: I've made a mistake, the pop-up where you introduce your credentials does'n appear.. so I can introduce the e-mail and password for login.. the second time when I press the login button the user is logged in automatically

Comment: I  don't want to make an aggressive logout, I just want to logout from my application..

Comment: I find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19356354/1749752, but I don't really understand how to implement it. Could you please post an example for me? thank you

Comment: So in the end I used this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14831349/1749752

Comment: can you post how you did it in an answer please ?